# Does this torque setting seem correct for a crank-pulley bolt?

Tags: renault, torque-specification, k7m

For a K7M engine:

Please can someone more experienced give me their impression on this torque setting for the crank-pulley bolt:

30nm +100 +-5degrees

I got this from the K7M Timing Belt instruction set. Just want to make sure. (For the imperial members 30nm = 22.12686ft-lb )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems reasonable.  Be sure you are NOT re-using the original bolt.  When used like this, called "torque-to-yield" the fastener has been stretched beyond its deformation limit and if re-used, it will not torque properly and may break.

Be careful about the angle, it's important!

So to do this you torque to 30 Nm, then rotate it an additional 100 degrees of rotation with a tolerance of +/- 5 degrees.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned that about a new bolt. 

The only problem is I hope I can source one because it seems backyard mechanics and diy'ers are slowly being deprived of footholds. One example is the lack of marking on crank casings these days. 

I am currently being told I have to buy the whole kit and not all of them come with bolts. But, anyway, I was tempted to use the same bolt, but now I will have another go at sourcing a new bolt. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: You definitely need to replace the bolt even if it means purchasing a kit that includes parts you don't need.

Comment: Prices are way too high. At this rate of inflation, it seems most people will shortly not be able to afford hydro-carbon based vehicles. 

Oh, wait...